# Code to place rows next to each other in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

I'm looking for a short code (or formula?) that I could use to rearrange my data, particularly to place rows next to each other (see picture).

[image: Rearrange rows next to each other]

Thank you.

The closest I found was a formula that combines the use of MOD and OFFSET (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tt4nUYVp2v0&ab_channel=MikeWong), but this does not quite do what I want.

Data:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  |  |
| **2** | 1 | 3112.5 | 947 |
| **3** | 2 | 3087.5 | 937.5 |
| **4** | 3 | 1271 | 1162 |
| **5** | 4 | 1086 | 1239 |
| **6** | 1 | 3112.5 | 947 |
| **7** | 2 | 3087.5 | 937.5 |
| **8** | 3 | 1271 | 1162 |
| **9** | 4 | 1086 | 1239 |
| **10** | 1 | 3112.5 | 947 |
| **11** | 2 | 3087.5 | 937.5 |
| **12** | 3 | 1271 | 1162 |
| **13** | 4 | 1086 | 1239 |
| **14** | 1 | 3112.5 | 947 |
| **15** | 2 | 3087.5 | 937.5 |
| **16** | 3 | 1271 | 1162 |
| **17** | 4 | 1086 | 1239 |
| **18** | 1 | 3112.5 | 947 |
| **19** | 2 | 3087.5 | 937.5 |
| **20** | 3 | 1271 | 1162 |
| **21** | 4 | 1086 | 1239 |

Comment: I can't access your link - can you describe in your question exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: I am not sure: but your screenshot doesn't look like "Excel 2010" - can you verify which version you are using - it makes a difference in the approach to solve your question

Comment: @CHill60 my software produces data points (x,y) in 4 lines or rows, I want these (x,y) data points to be beside each other in 1 row.

Comment: @Ike, sorry this is Microsoft 365, I will change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged Excel 2010 it was a bit challenging getting the results as shown (paste formula and drag to right/down):

```
=IFERROR(
         IF(COLUMN(A1)-1 / ((COLUMN(A1)-1)/2<=MAX($A$2:$A$21)) / (ROW(A1)<=(ROWS($A$2:$A$21)/MAX($A$2:$A$21))),
            INDEX($B$2:$C$21,
                  1+(ROW(A1)-1)*MAX($A$2:$A$21)+(COLUMN(A1)-2)/2,
                  1+ISODD(COLUMN(A1))),
            ROW(A1)),
         "")
```

[image]

With Office 365 this all can be a lot easier:
`=LET(w,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B2:C21),8),HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(w)),w))`

or dynamic:

```
=LET(range,A2:C21,
     pattern,TAKE(range,,1),
     values,DROP(range,,1),
     n,MAX(pattern),
     wrap,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(values),n*COLUMNS(values)),
HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(wrap)),wrap))
```

On Beta you could also use PIVOTBY:
`=PIVOTBY(1+INT((ROW(B2:C21)-ROW(B2))/MAX(A2:A21)),A2:A21,B2:C21,SUM,,0,,0)`

[image]

Comment: Brilliant solution using `PIVOTBY()`

Comment: Personally I liked the wraprows best, but I wanted to try out PIVOTBY as well.

Comment: @P.b Thank you and sorry I put wrong it is Office 365 not Excel 2010

Comment: please make sure next time you post a question, to not tag it falsively; as you can see the difference between Excel 2010 (1st part of answer) and Office 365 (the following oneliner).
If my answer, or Horseyrides answer helped you, please mark that answer by ticking the green v-sign on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

PowerQuery add-in was introduced in Excel 2013 by Microsoft and was made backward compatible with Excel 2010. Once installed, bring data into powerquery, noting that it does not have headers.  In later versions of excel, just directly use data .. from table/range...

Paste this code into home ... advanced editor ...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], // preserve your first row from what is autogenerated in place of this row
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
RowIndex = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 4), Int64.Type}}),
Part1 = Table.SelectColumns(RowIndex,{"Column1", "Column2", "Index"}),
Part2=  Table.TransformColumns(Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(RowIndex,{"Column1", "Column3", "Index"}),{{"Column3", "Column2"}}),{{"Column1",each _ + .5, type number}}),
#"Sorted" = Table.Sort(Part1&Part2,{{"Column1", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted", {{"Column1", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted", {{"Column1", type text}}, "en-US")[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

load the output with file ... close and load .... into excel and refresh with right click or by VBA refresh on the powerquery

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer but I made mistake, it is Excel 2021 (Microsoft 365) and not Excel 2010. Apologies. I tried WRAPROWS solution by @P.b and it worked.

Comment: As you prefer but this answer would still work for excel 2021